# Keep one HDRI for lighting and another for the background?

Tags: modeling, node-editor, geometry-nodes, compositing-nodes, hdri

[image]

So how would I keep one hdri for lighting and use (and be able to edit / adjust) another one for the sky?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mix your 2 *Background* nodes through a *Mix Shader* and use the *Is Camera Ray* output of an *(Input) Light Path*:

[image]

Comment: maybe you should mention that you should use the camera as texture coordinate?

Comment: @Chris I'm not sure what you mean, actually what will be plugged into the top input of the Mix Shader input will be what will light the scene, while what will be plugged in the bottom input will be what will be seen as background, I thought this what the OP wanted to know?

Comment: i meant the "not showing" texture coordinate node ;)

Comment: @Chris The _Environment Texture_ uses by default _Generated_ coordinates when nothing is plugged in - and to use different HDRIs for lighting and background it is not necessary to set the coordinates to _Camera_, in which case it is irrelevant what is plugged in there since it would work without any _Vector_ input.

Comment: I think that the OP wants an invisible background that will be the one that will enlight the objects, and another one that we will see but that won't act on the objects

Comment: @moonboots That's how I understood the question as well.